# How is the ['user']['country'] attribute set in the signed request?

Tags: facebook, api

How is this value set? Is it an option in your account settings? Based on your IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contact at Facebook informed me that they always use geoip for setting the ['user']['country'] attribute in the signed request.  For other areas, such as post targeting, many signals are used to best determine the user's country.  IP address, checkins + self declared location figure strongly in the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

From testing, it appears to be completely based on an IP lookup.  It doesn't seem to be related at all to the location values in the user object/table.